# Xcode not run any project, not show simulator list and got freeze on run

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios-simulator, ios10, xcode8

Last night, Xcode suddenly stopped running my all projects. Only one project will run and shows the error:

```
XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Before the build, I pressed "alt+shift+command+k" to clean the build folder.  Now, the simulatorlist is also not showing.

I working on an iOS application, using swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the cause of problem but after lots of hit and try now everything is working fine.

The solution I find to show the simulator list back are as following step:-

1.Delete my Xcode by removing it from **Applications** by move it to trash.

2.Delete /Users/Sushobhit/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

3.Restart your mac (this step is optional but I personally recommend it).

4.Download latest version(don't download beta version and you can download it from App Store or  form Apple developer account in downloads)

5.install them and simulator will be show back.

Note - Please comment if you have better solution or find me wrong.

Comment: Deleting Xcode and resinstalling it is almost never ever the solution to any problem.  The real thing that helped in your scenario is likely rebooting your system because deleting ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator is a sure way to mess up your system (unless you’ve also made sure that CoreSimulatorService is not running as well).

Comment: Also, the error with swiftc is in no way related to your issue with the sim.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I agree with you thats why I asked people to find the better way and I reboot my system many times when dealing this problem but it didn't work for me so I have to do above steps.